# Gnat (ada95) comfused by error "... is not visible" using my package

Tags: ada

Using Gnat 7.4.0.

I'm an Ada noob, and confused by the error message:

```
$ gnat make list_test.adb
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-7 -c list_test.adb
list_test.adb:9:18: "List" is not visible (more references follow)
list_test.adb:9:18: non-visible declaration at linked_list.ads:19
x86_64-linux-gnu-gnatmake-7: "list_test.adb" compilation error
```

I don't understand why my `List` is not visible.

I'm trying to write a linked list with a generic payload to teach myself Ada.  I wrote a binary tree with a similar layout (except the generic) which did not exhibit this error.

The `.ads`:

```
with Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation;

generic
    type Payload_Type is private;

package Linked_List is

    type List_Node;
    type List_Node_Pointer is access all List_Node;

    type List_Node is
    record
        payload : Payload_Type;
        next    : List_Node_Pointer := null;
        prev    : List_Node_Pointer := null;
    end record;

    type List is
    record
        head  : List_Node_Pointer := null;
        tail  : List_Node_Pointer := null;
        count : Natural           := 0;
    end record;

    type List_Pointer is access all List;


    procedure pushTail( base    : in List;
                        payload : in Payload_Type );

    procedure pushHead( base    : in List;
                        payload : in Payload_Type );

    function popTail( base : List ) return Payload_Type;

    function contains( base    : List;
                       payload : Payload_Type ) return Boolean;


private

    procedure free is new Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation( List_Node, List_Node_Pointer );

end Linked_List;
```

And the `.adb`: (for the sake of completeness)

```
with Ada.Assertions;

package body Linked_List is

    procedure pushTail( base    : in out List;
                        payload : in Payload_Type ) is
    begin
        if ( base.head = null ) then
            -- list is empy
            base.head  := new List_Node;
            base.tail  := base.head;
            base.head.payload := payload;
        else
            -- list is not empty, add to the tail
            base.tail.next := new List_Node;
            base.tail.next.prev := base.tail;
            base.tail := base.tail.next;
            base.tail.payload := payload;
        end if;
        base.count := base.count + 1;
    end push;


    ...  -- More definitions for pushHead(), popTail(), contains()

private

end Linked_List;
```

The `list_test.adb` is something like:

```
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Linked_List;

procedure List_Test is
    my_list    : List;
    found      : Boolean;
begin
    List.pushTail( my_list, Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String( "First" ) );
    List.pushTail( my_list, Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String( "2nd" ) );

    ... etc.
```

Originally I had the syntax:

```
my_list : Linked_List.List;
```

But Gnat didn't like it - I don't understand why that wasn't accepted either.

EDIT: I've also tried

```
procedure List_Test is
    package List_String is new List( Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String );

    my_list    : List_String;
```

But I get the same `"List" is not visible` error.

EDIT2:

```
with Linked_List;

procedure List_Test is
    package String_List is new List( Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String ); use String_List;

    my_list    : String_List;
```

Still generates the error:

```
list_test.adb:10:32: "List" is not visible
list_test.adb:10:32: non-visible declaration at linked_list.ads:10
list_test.adb:10:89: "String_List" is undefined (more references follow)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the `Linked_List` package is generic, you cannot reference the type `Linked_List.List` directly. You can only reference the `List` type in the instantiated package. Hence, try insert `use List_String;` directly after the instantiation of the generic package `Linked_List`, or use `List_String.List` to reference the `List` type in the `List_String` package:

```
procedure List_Test is

   package List_String is 
      new Linked_List (Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String);
   use List_String;

   my_list : List
```

or

```
procedure List_Test is

   package List_String is 
      new Linked_List (Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String);

   my_list : List_String.List
```